# check if given integer is sum of given array elements (or part of them) using only recursion

Tags: arrays, recursion

Given an array of integers, I need to implement a function that checks if some partial array equals to a given sum, **using recursion only**. The function to be implemented looks like this:

```
boolean isPartialSum(int[] array, int total);
```

I can also use the following function, also recursively only:

```
boolean isPartialSum(int[] array, int index, int total);
```

No use of loops is allowed, as well as no other helper funcions. 
For input of {1,5,8} as array and 9 as total the answer should be true, because 1+8=9.

Comment: Are then any specifications about the data set i.e. the array provided?

Comment: No, just that they are all integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an array `a[]` with length `n`.  Then the pseudocode for finding if the sum of some elements gives the number `s`:

```
boolean isPartialSum (a[], i, s):
    if s == 0:
      return true
    if i == n:
      if a[n] == s:
        return true
      else:
        return false
    if i < n:
      if isPartialSum(a, i + 1, s - a[i]):
        return true
      else if isPartialSum(a, i + 1, s):
        return true
      else:
        return false
```

To find out if some elements of the arrat add up to `s`, simply call

```
isPartialSum(a, 1, s)
```

assuming the index of your array is numbered from `1`.

**Update proof:** the algorithm above recursively iterates through all subsets of `a[]` (which is `2^n` subsets) and for each decides whether the elements adds up to `s`. Hence, the algorithm is correct.

Comment: This won't suffice except for only certain cases. Its not that straight forward.

Comment: That does not work in case of sum of array elements that are not adjucent.

Comment: Added the case when s = 0 and the proof that the algorithm works. **ps**: correct me if I understood the task wrong.